# Using dictionary from Django view in .html Javascript loop (SyntaxError - unexpected token: &#x27)

Tags: javascript, django, loops, dictionary, syntax-error

I'm working on a Django project, and when I try to load a dictionary using Javascript, I get SyntaxError - unexpected token: &#x27

In my .html file, I am using {{ customer_tabledata }} to import from my views. The problem is it's trying to load &#x27 and not the quotation mark. How can I convert from &#x27 to "?

In my .html file:

```
<script>
    let tableData = {{ customer_tabledata }};

    function loadTableData(tableData) {
        const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableData');
        let dataHTML = '';

        for(let data of tableData) {
            dataHTML += `<tr><td>${data}</td></tr>` ;
        }

        tableBody.innerHTML = dataHTML;
</script>
```

In my views:

```
customer_tabledata = {'site_1' : {'revenue' : 900 }, {'partner_share' : 450}, 'site_2 : {'revenue' : 1500 }, {'partner_share' : 750}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add "|safe" inside the python tag, it works!

> let tableData = {{ customer_tabledata|**safe**}};